# How python interpret a function as a generator

Tags: python, generator, yield

I know that if a "yield" statement is present in a function it will be treated as a generator.
But how does python interpreter works in that case when the function(generator) called for the first time.I mean when the code is interpreted i think first "gen" will get bind to a function object. Why it doesn't execute the statements before yield unlike normal functions or classes when called for first time. How does it put a hold on the execution of the print function before yield

```
>>> def gen():
...    print("In gen")
...    yield 1
...    yield 2
... 
>>> type(gen)
<type 'function'>
>>> a = gen
>>> type(a)
<type 'function'>
>>> 
>>> b = a()
>>> type(b)
<type 'generator'>
>>> b.next()
In gen
1
>>> b.next()
2
>>>
```

Comment: Because Python generators are, by definition, [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). They only start yielding output once you start consuming them (i.e. iterate over them).

Comment: I mean before going to yield , why it doesn't execute the statements before yield. How does the interpreter know about it.

Comment: In addition to @unutbu's answer: Because Python treats a function body with a  `yield` statement differently. Once you put a `yield` in there, it knows you'll be defining a generator, not a regular function. Try putting `yield` and `return` (with an argument) in the same function, Python won't let you compile that code, even if you never use that function.

Comment: @Lukas : Cool, thanks. A little more explanation on def executable will help.

Comment: See [The `yield` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement): *"Using a yield statement in a function definition is sufficient to cause that definition to create a generator function instead of a normal function."* **How** exactly the Python bytecode compilation process works is highly involved and shouldn't have to concern you.

Comment: If you *do* want to poke around in Python's internals, I suggest you look at the builtin [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#compile) function and compile a few code snippets, and then disassemble them using [`dis.dis()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis). (You can also directly disassemble functions if you like). You can also try [`dis.code_info(gen)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.code_info) on Python >= 3.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Python *parses* the `def` statement, it decides if the code is defining a generator or a function. If the code contains a `yield` expression, then it is a generator. So when the generator function `a` is called, it returns a `generator object`, `b`.

The code inside the `def` statement is not executed until `b.next()` is called.

---

Consider these two functions:

```
def gen():
     print('In gen')
     yield 1
     yield 2


def func():
     print('In gen')
```

Although `gen` and `func` are both functions, 
Python knows that `gen` is a generator:

```
In [96]: import inspect

In [101]: inspect.isgeneratorfunction(gen)
Out[101]: True

In [102]: inspect.isgeneratorfunction(func)
Out[102]: False
```

If you look inside the inspect module you see

```
def isgeneratorfunction(object):
    """Return true if the object is a user-defined generator function.

    Generator function objects provides same attributes as functions.

    See help(isfunction) for attributes listing."""
    return bool((isfunction(object) or ismethod(object)) and
                object.func_code.co_flags & CO_GENERATOR)
```

So apparently Python checks this first before executing the code inside the function.

Comment: How does the def statement does it without reaching the control to the block inside the function. How does it find it?

Comment: I don't how how def works, so a little more explanation will help. I thought it just creates a function object and bind a name to it.

Comment: All of the code gets _compiled_.  The compiler inspects the contents of the function definition, finds a `yield` statement, and determines this object is, in fact, a generator.

Comment: I had heard that , python only does syntax compilation, i guess there is more to it then. Any suggestion i can find more info on this?

Comment: @kingsdeb You can read some documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/devguide/compiler.html).

Comment: @kingdeb: Although `dis.dis(gen)` shows no indication that `gen` is a generator function, `gen.func_code.co_flags` has a flag indicating that `gen` is a generator. So the `def` statement is creating a function object that knows its a generator. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Don't confuse when your code is executed from when it is interpreted / compiled.  There are an interpret / compile phase before the code can be run.  You can explore this in a simpler way without generators -- put a syntax error in a function definition and see what happens.  The error will be generated when that code is defined (e.g. typed into interpreter or loaded via `import`), before you get a chance to run it.  The function vs. generator termination is made in the same way -- when the code is loaded & compiled, before you can execute it.